# PHP else if does nothing

Tags: php, mysql

I've got function in PHP. Instruction "if" works perfectly, but the problem is in elseif part, because it does nothing :/

```
function getEffectiveVotes($id) {
    /**
        Returns an integer
        **/
    $votes = getAllVotes($id);
    $effectiveVote = $votes[0] - $votes[1];
    return $effectiveVote;
}

$id = $_POST['id'];
$action = $_POST['action'];

//get the current votes
$cur_votes = getAllVotes($id);

//ok, now update the votes
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if ($_POST['id']) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $id = mysql_real_escape_String($id);

    $ip_sql = mysql_query("select ip_add from Voting_IP where mes_id_fk='$id' and ip_add='$ip'");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($ip_sql);

    if ($count == 0) {
        if ($action == 'vote_up') //voting up
        {
            $votes_up = $cur_votes[0] + 1;
            $q = "UPDATE entries SET votes_up = $votes_up WHERE id = $id";

            $sql_in = "insert into Voting_IP (mes_id_fk,ip_add) values ('$id','$ip')";
            mysql_query($sql_in);
        }
        elseif($action == 'vote_down') //voting down
        {
            $votes_down = $cur_votes[1] + 1;
            $q = "UPDATE entries SET votes_down = $votes_down WHERE id = $id";

            $sql_in = "insert into Voting_IP (mes_id_fk,ip_add) values ('$id','$ip')";
            mysql_query($sql_in);
        }
    }
    elseif($count !== 0) {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
        echo '</script>';
    }

} ?>
```

The problem is in this part. Is it in wrong place or wrong syntax? I haven't got any errors.

```
elseif($count!==0){
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
    echo '</script>';
}
```

Comment: only this perhaps " != "

Comment: What is the value of `$count`?

Comment: It looks like you have an extra `}` there, I tidied up your code

Comment: wouldn't else be enough instead of elseif?

Comment: I was just thinking isn't type casing the posted "id" as (int) would be enough instead of using mysql_real_escape_String ?

Comment: @Prashank, no i think you would still be able to break out of the query since get requests append ?id= to the url

Comment: is there a security risk in type casing to int for POST?

Answer (score 0):

you have a syntax error

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_String($id);
```

should be

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
```

als your `elseif` statement should be an `if` statement, and your wonky `$count` variable can be replaced with the faster code below

```
    if(mysql_num_rows($ip_sql) > 0){
    echo 
    '
    <script language="javascript">
    alert("message successfully sent")
    </script>
    ';
    }
```

additionally, it might be time to upgrade from the `mysql_*` functions as well. they will be removed soon from php from what i understand. even now with error reporting set to all you will see a warning about them being deprecated.

Comment: I thought it was just a typo with uppercase "S". Cuz he didn't say anything about any error :|

Comment: php doesn't throw error's for misspelled functions. in fact, 95% of the time, i find i've misspelled a function i made when attempting to call it in a script.

Comment: Function names are case *insensitive* in PHP

Comment: hmmm! i know function names are insensitive :/

Comment: @user1950221 dig around on my github you should be able to find something useful there. github.com/r3wt/openex.git